# Tomar solo un valor de una consulta MySQL en Flask Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Tengo una consulta en Flask Python Mysql, y necesito tomar solo uno de los valores para asignarlo a una variable, el valor que necesito tomar es e_grado:

```
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('select e_id, e_nombres, e_apellidos, e_grado, a_docident, a_nombres, a_apellidos, a_telefono from estudiantes INNER JOIN acudientes ON e_acudiente = a_id  where e_id = {0}'.format(e_id))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    grado = cur.fetchone(3)
```

Ese valor e_grado necesito asignarlo a la variable grado, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?, traté de hacerlo con grado = cur.fetchone(3) pero veo que no es la manera correcta.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: en el cursos puedes pasarle `cursor(dictionary=True)` y hacer `grado = data["e_grado"]`

Comment: Hola Bryro, agradezco mucho tu ayuda, te cuento que me sale un error. "TypeError: 'Cursor' object is not callable", así tengo el código:

'''def imprimirapertura(e_id):
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('select e_id, e_nombres, e_apellidos, e_grado, a_docident, a_nombres, a_apellidos, a_telefono from estudiantes INNER JOIN acudientes ON e_acudiente = a_id  where e_id = {0}'.format(e_id))
    data = cur.fetchall()
    cur(dictionary=True)
    grado = data["e_grado"]''' Si le coloco cursor(dicionary=True) me dice: NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

Comment: es que es asi.... `mysql.connection.cursor(dictionary=True)`

Comment: Hola Bryro, lo intenté y me sale este error: TypeError: cursor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'